# Detecting breaking changes using Pact.IO (PactNet)

Tags: c#, pact

I'm trying to use PactNet for contract testing. After some issues i managed to get it up and running (Consumer test -> Broker -> Provider tests), but one thing confuses me:

Lets say I have a contract f.e.:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Weather forecast Id 
/// </summary>
public int Id { get; init; }

/// <summary>
/// Temperature in celsius
/// </summary>
public int Temperature { get; init; }
```

Everything works fine. Lets change the datatype of Temperature field on the producer side and make it for example nullable double:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Weather forecast Id 
/// </summary>
public int Id { get; init; }

/// <summary>
/// Temperature in celsius
/// </summary>
public double? Temperature { get; init; } // Changed to nullable double
```

pact.json:

```json
{
  "description": "A valid request for a single weather data",
  "providerStates": [
    {
      "name": "Weather forecast with id = 10 exists"
    },
    {
      "name": "Any tenant context"
    }
  ],
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/WeatherForecasts/10"
  },
  "response": {
    "body": {
      "Id": 1,
      "Temperature": 6
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "matchingRules": {
      "body": {
        "$.Id": {
          "combine": "AND",
          "matchers": [
            {
              "match": "integer"
            }
          ]
        },
        "$.Temperature": {
          "combine": "AND",
          "matchers": [
            {
              "match": "integer"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "header": {}
    },
    "status": 200
  }
}
```

When running the tests against current pact, it seems everything is fine, the test will pass. But this type of change IS a breaking change. Shouldn't Pact detect such breaking change? Isn't that its purpose? But there is no information about datatype nor nullability in pact.json file. So far, I am able to detect only missing properties in a response.

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

> When running the tests against current pact, it seems everything is fine, the test will pass. But this type of change IS a breaking change. Shouldn't Pact detect such breaking change? Isn't that its purpose? But there is no information about datatype nor nullability in pact.json file. So far, I am able to detect only missing properties in a response.

Yes! It is a breaking change, and if your provider returns a `null` for that field it should pick up the issue.

If you need to be able to support an optional field (in a consumer test), you would need to test both scenarios. See https://docs.pact.io/faq#why-is-there-no-support-for-specifying-optional-attributes for more.